# ModernUI ModernTab Link Click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm looking for a click event or something similar for use with the ModernUI WPF's ModernTab.

I'm currently using ModernUI WPF (http://mui.codeplex.com/) and I'm trying to use a ModernTab control as a list of employees, which I'll then click and open their details in the Source page.

Problem is, I am going to be creating the list of employees at runtime from a database, which will mean that I'll need to add the links manually. Therefore, I need to be able to hook some click event from the tab so I can find out what user to display- but I don't see a property that'll work. The closest I can see is that the ModernTab parent control has click events, but they only register if I click an empty part of the control.

The only other thing I can think of is to generate a custom panel for each employee at runtime and set it to the Source attribute when I create the list, which I'd rather not do if possible.

Here's my panel:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Schedule.Pages.EditEmployees"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <mui:ModernTab Layout="List" Name="employeeTabList" >
        <mui:ModernTab.Links >
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Create New..." Source="/Pages/EditEmployeeDetail.xaml" />
        </mui:ModernTab.Links>
    </mui:ModernTab>
</Grid>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one example of "hijacking" the click on the ModernTab. Here, you can force the content to load in the top frame, for example:

Handle the `SelectedSourceChanged` event of the ModernTab:

`employeeTabList.SelectedSourceChanged += employeeTabList_SelectedSourceChanged;`

```
void employeeTabList_SelectedSourceChanged(object sender, SourceEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source.OriginalString.EndsWith("EditEmployeeDetail.xaml"))
    {
        var url = "/Pages/EditEmployeeDetail.xaml";
        var bb = new BBCodeBlock();
        bb.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative), this, NavigationHelper.FrameTop);
        // You may want to set some property in that page's ViewModel, for example, indicating the selected User ID.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a fragment to the Uri representing each employee when links are created. Then for the EmployeeDetail usercontrol implement the IContent Interface (specifically OnFragmentNavigation to initialize the data using the fragment). Sample code here -

http://mui.codeplex.com/discussions/455846